# Question on IConfiguration's DI scope in an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scope

I have 2 service classes that call `IConfiguration` like so:

```
public class ReportingService
{
    readonly string? password;

    public ReportingService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        url = configuration["JSReport:URL"];
    }
    ...
}

public class SerialNumberService : ISerialNumberService
{
    readonly string serialNumberEmail;

    public SerialNumberService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        serialNumberEmail = configuration["Inventory:SerialNumberEmail"]
                            ?? throw new Exception($"Missing configuration value Inventory:SerialNumberEmail");
    }
    ...
}
```

However, each service is scoped differently:

```
services.AddSingleton<ReportingService>();
services.AddScoped<ISerialNumberService, SerialNumberService>();
```

At 'seemingly' random times the `SerialNumberService` class errors, with an exception

> Missing configuration value Inventory:SerialNumberEmail

The configuration file (`appsettings.json`) obviously hasn't changed. `ReportingService` never has this trouble.

I notice in some examples of DI in Core (ie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage), values are not read in service constructors, but an instance of the `IConfiguration` object is attached in the constructor, and used in the various methods.

Is it something to do with that? Or the scope?

Why would our code sometimes fail to read a value in the configuration? What am I missing here?

Comment: To clarify: Are you saying that sometimes the value is present in `IConfiguration` and sometimes it is not? Anything is possible, but that sounds unlikely. I'd write an integration test that uses the application's `Startup` and config files and see whether the error happens. https://scotthannen.org/blog/2021/11/18/testserver-how-did-i-not-know.html You can either copy the settings files into the test project or link the file.

Comment: I should clarify, that the Blazor app is calling these services directly. I was wondering if the classes were getting instantiated asynchronously in such a way that sometimes the service would get created before the app had access to the config settings.

Comment: In order to create `SerialNumberService` DI first resolves dependencies, in this case `IConfiguration`. It's a singleton, but values retrieved from it can be reloaded if their providers are configured as such. DI provides `IConfiguration` but configuration providers supply configuration values, and those providers can refresh their values e.g. standard `appsettings.json` have such option. `IConfiguration` is one of few special services that are already initialized even before the DI container is built. That's why you can inject it into your Startup class where you register services for DI.

Comment: If you see value or no value for `Inventory:SerialNumberEmail` key at random times, inspect all you configuration sources e.g. the appsettings files and how are they registered. Are you allowing for reload on change? What configuration sources do you have? Is `Inventory:SerialNumberEmail` key duplicated in more than one configuration source?